# Does UU* is a projection in Hilbert space iff U*U is a projection?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space.
Let $U:H\rightarrow H$ be a bounded linear operator.

Does $U^{*}U$ is a projection implies $UU^{*}$ is a projection?

Of course, once we prove this, it follows that one of them is a projection is equivalent to another one is a projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  We have the following equivalences:

(a) $U^*U$ is a projection,

(b) $U^*UU^*=U^*$,

(c) $UU^*U=U$,

(d) $UU^*$ is a projection.

The proofs that (b) implies (a), (c) implies (d), and (b) and (c) are equivalent, are trivial.  To show (a) implies (c), by the $C^*$-identity we have 
\begin{align*}
\|UU^*U-U\|^2&=\|(U^*UU^*-U^*)(UU^*U-U)\|\\
&=\|U^*UU^*UU^*U-2U^*UU^*U+U^*U\|\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Then proving that (d) implies (b) is completely analogous.

Comment: Is the sign of u*u of the second last equality should be positive?

Comment: Yes it should, thanks for pointing that out.